# Solving difference of cubes: what rule requires multiple solutions

Tags: algebra-precalculus

For my own amusement, I am working through `Beginning and Intermediate Algebra` by Tyler Wallace.

In Example 483 ( Quadratic In Form ) we arrive at the factors

```
  $x^3 =1; x^3=8$
```

Taking the cube root of each side gives us 1;2

Both answers are 'correct' but the answer is not complete. We need to factor the difference in cubes expressions $`x^3-1` and x^3-8.

What is the rule that says we have to go on to break down the difference in cubes even though it *seems* we have an answer to the equation.

Answer (score 2):

For example:

$$x^3=1
\implies x^3-1=0$$
$$\implies (x-1)(x^2+x+1)=0 $$

Clearly, $x=1$ is a root.

The other root lies in the solution to the equation $x^2+x+1 = 0$

Of course, it's discriminant is negative, so it has no real solutions, but you can find complex solutions using the quadratic formula:

$\frac{-1+\sqrt{3}i}{2},\frac{-1-\sqrt{3}i}{2}$

Answer (score 1):

The 'Rule' is called the [Fundamental Theorem of Algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_algebra), which states that every (non-zero, with complex coefficients) polynomial (in one variable) of degree $n$ must have $n$ roots in $\mathbb C$, including multiplicities (e.g. $(x-1)^2$ has a root of $x=1$ with multiplicity $2$.)

This rule shows that there could be roots we are missing if we simply find the obvious roots of such polynomials.

Answer (score 1):

In this example the author isn't looking for *a* solution, but for *all* solutions.

The solutions $x=1$ and $x=2$ are the only solutions in the real numbers: If you use the fact that the function $f(x)=x^3$ is increasing, then it follows that there can be only one solution to $x^3=1$, and to $x^3=8$, and indeed you are done when you have found $x=1$ and $x=2$.

But over the complex numbers this argument doesn't hold. There could be more solutions. The factorization
$$x^3-1=(x-1)(x^2+x+1),$$
helps you to find them; either $x=1$ or $x^2+x+1=0$. Then the quadratic formula tells you precisely which two complex numbers satisfy $x^2+x+1=0$. The same goes for $x^3-8$.

Answer (score -1):

$$a^3-b^3=(a-b)(a^2+ab+b^2)$$
We can prove it by expending.

So $$x^3-8=(x-2)(x^2+2x+4)=(x-2)((x+1)^2+3).$$
I hope it what you are looking  for.